# Cakephp with ACL not redirecting when not enough permissions

Tags: cakephp, permissions, acl, redirect

I've been working in an Cakephp website and is almost done, except for the problem on the title, what i need to do is to redirect to one page if the user has not enough access level to continue and it actually works well if you write the url in the address bar, but not when a button that should direct to the same address is pressed.

This is my AppController class

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
        )
    ),
    'Session'
);
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

public function beforeFilter() {
    //Configure AuthComponent
    //debug($this->params,true);
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'add');
    $this->Auth->authError = "Error";
            if (isset($this->params['requested'])) $this->Auth->allow($this->action); 
}
```

And this is an example of a link to an "add" page and if the user is not allowed to perform this action, should be redirect to the page is configured in my AppController

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image("add.png", array("alt" => "Agregar nueva encuesta","title" => "Agregar nueva encuesta")),
        array('controller'=>'Surveys','action'=>'add',$beneficiary['Beneficiary']['id']),
        array('escape' => false));?>
```

So, to be clear, if the user writes the address "myserver/Beneficiaries/add/parameter" is redirected to the page that shows that he can't do that action, but if he presses the link nothing happens, he can't add anything, but I need that redirection.

I would appreciate any advice.

I hope my explanation was clear, my english is far from being perfect :)

Edit:

I decided to follow the advice of the user Ben Hitchcock about using the web debugger "Charles". This is what I got

**Writting at the address bar**

Request
GET /Projects/SUISEPV2/Beneficiaries/edit/1 HTTP/1.1
Host    localhost
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Cookie  CAKEPHP=7399cvgls9gurk37ubes1fknf0
Connection  keep-alive

Responde
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date    Mon, 20 Jan 2014 16:54:56 GMT
Server  Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.22
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.22
Location    myserver/Projects/SUISEPV2/posts/add
Content-Length  0
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8

**Pressing the link**

Request:
GET /Projects/SUISEPV2/Beneficiaries/edit/1 HTTP/1.1
Host    localhost
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Referer myserver/Projects/SUISEPV2/Beneficiaries
Cookie  CAKEPHP=7399cvgls9gurk37ubes1fknf0
Connection  keep-alive

Response:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date    Mon, 20 Jan 2014 16:55:33 GMT
Server  Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.22
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.22
Location    myserver/Projects/SUISEPV2/Beneficiaries
Content-Length  0
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8

Unfortunately I still can't see what's wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't the link have 'controller'=>'Beneficiaries', instead of 'controller'=>'Surveys'?

Comment: Not in this case, the action of that button is to add one survey to the selected beneficiary, but is not important, the problem happens even if I try to edit or eliminate anything that the user is not allowed to do.

Comment: You might be going into a redirect loop.  I'd try running Charles (web proxy) and examining what's being sent to the server, and what comes back.

Comment: I installed Charles to check what's going on and edited my question, i'm sorry, i can't find what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution and it worked better than what I wanted.

In my layout I added the next line

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
```

and now i can show the message I configured in the beforeFilter function at AppController class

```
$this->Auth->authError = "Custom error message here";
```

The result is the following:

If I press the link button im not being redirected but I get a message showing what i want to tell to the user.
If i write the address I'm being redirected to the error page and also I get the flash message.